# Sum Query in Vertica Database

Tags: mysql, vertica

I am converting my MySql queries to run over Vertica database for one of our projects where we are facing problem with executing SUM aggregate function.

**MYSQL Query:**

```
SELECT event.plateNumber, event.plateCodeId, sum(  event.sourceId 
in (1,2,3) ) as 'sum'  from event group by event.plateNumber, event.plateCodeId
having sum(  event.sourceId in (1,2,3) ) > 0  ;
```

I am trying to run this query in vertica database and having below exception.

**Error: Function sum(boolean) does not exist, or permission is denied for sum(boolean)**

When we refer to vertica [documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Aggregate/SUMAggregate.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CSQL%2520Functions%7CAggregate%2520Functions%7C_____32) about SUM aggregate function, it looks like there is no difference in function signature.

I tried to look over different sites but could not get any help to transform above mentioned MYSQL Query to vertica Query.

Can anyone help regarding that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The sum() predicate is supported by Vertica, but doesn't support booleans.
You need to convert your boolean value to numeric first. Since [cast](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/LanguageElements/Operators/DataTypeCoercionOperatorsCAST.htm) doesn't known how to convert a boolean to numeric, your best option is to use a [case](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/LanguageElements/Expressions/CASEExpressions.htm). For example :

```
SELECT event.plateNumber, 
       event.plateCodeId, 
       sum(  CASE WHEN event.sourceId in (1,2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'sum' 
    FROM event 
    GROUP BY event.plateNumber, event.plateCodeId
```

Comment: I dont want columns having sum 0 in query result.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference for a SUM predicate, but if you want to replace 0 with null, you can just remove the 'ELSE 0" part of the statement : sum(  CASE WHEN event.sourceId in (1,2,3) THEN 1 END) as 'sum' .

Comment: @mauro answer does the same and is indeed more elegant

Answer (score 1):

What about...

```
SELECT 
    event.plateNumber, 
    event.plateCodeId, 
    sum((event.sourceId in (1,2,3))::INTEGER) as 'sum'
FROM 
    event 
GROUP BY 
    event.plateNumber, event.plateCodeId
HAVING 
    sum((event.sourceId in (1,2,3))::INTEGER) > 0  ;
```